# Trying to toggle random LEDs with a XOR and bit shift operator

Tags: c++, random, embedded, xc8

For a model railroad project, I am trying to toggle LEDs by using a random number generator (rand()) which produces x and then shifting 1 to the left by x on the LATC register on a PIC16F15325.  (I am an enthusiastic hobbyist, but still with so much to learn, completely self-taught.)  I am using XC8 and PICkit 3.

I am using the 16F15325 pic, and, in my mind, the following code should

- (A) generate a random number (pseudo is ok) between 0 and 5 (this is x) and
- (B) toggle bits C0 through C5 (each connected to an LED in the LATC register) by shifting 1 by x bits (i.e., 0 to 5) and by applying an XOR to that pin.

Given that this is in an infinite loop, then each time the code loops, it should toggle at least one LED.  This works about 90% of the time, but sometimes it doesn't result in a toggle, and it's driving me nuts.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>         /* For uint8_t definition */
#include <stdbool.h>        /* For true/false definition */
#include "configs.c"

void main(void) {

InitProgram();   // THIS SETS UP THE TRIS AND SETS THE C PORT TO OUTPUT

//  DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES

int x;             //  GENERAL PURPOSE VARIABLE TO USE ON THE FLY

LATC = 0b00111111;

while(1)
{
    x = rand() % 6;   //  SHOULD GENERATE 0 THROUGH 5 B/C NO "+ 1"

    LATC = LATC ^ 1 << x;

    //  I HAVE ALSO TRIED LATC = LATC ^ 1 << (char) x;

    //  THERE IS A ONE SECOND DELAY HERE

 }
}
```

As noted, this very often works on each run through the loop, but about 10% of the time, no LED will toggle.  90% of the time, one of the LEDs toggles.

Comment: logic looks right. blame the hardware.

Comment: Not running any interrupts, correct?

Comment: Have you tested all the LEDs individually?

Comment: PORTC defaults to analog mode.  You did switch to digital mode in addition to setting the pin direction, correct?

Comment: I am not running any interrupts.  Each of the LEDs works.  When I replace this random generator code with a for loop (0 to 5) it properly toggles each LED (like a chase light).  PORTC is initialized as follows:

Comment: void InitProgram(void)
    {
        TRISA = 0x00;
        TRISC = 0x00;
        ANSELA = 0x00;
        ANSELC = 0x00;
        LATA = 0x00;
        LATC = 0x00;
        PORTA = 0x00;
       PORTC = 0x00;
    }

Comment: As I/O port is sometimes not as fast as the core. If the GPIO needs many CPU cycles to toggle, you'll miss some of the cases. But if that was the problem, it would go away if you single-step through the program.

Comment: Other than that, I find no problems with the code. You could ask on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead and include both the code and a simple schematic over how you drive the LEDs (there's a schematic editor on the site). Lots of PIC gurus there and questions about microcontrollers are always on-topic, even if it's firmware questions.

Comment: HA!  I FOUND THE ANSWER!!!  (That's newbie excitement.)  I created a desktop C++ app with essentially the same code, and it created proper output, so I just knew something had to be wrong in the XC8 environment.  I searched the Microchip website and found a link that describes the bug in the rand() function, based on whether it's C90 or C99 (with my project being C99, where the problem is).  Link is here:  [link](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1077569.aspx)  Many thanks to those of you who responded.  I am a lawyer by trade, and I never have anyone to talk to about this stuff!!

Comment: In case it ever gets eliminated, here's the simple solution.  Take the random int generated by rand() and & it with 0x7fff.  Then run the modulo formula.  Like this:  x = rand() & 0x7fff; x = x % 10; That will return a (pseudo) random number between 0 and 9 (add + 1 if you want between 1 and x).  The rand.c file in C99 uses a 64 bit number and shifts it, but can leave a 1 in the bit that makes it a negative number.  To solve that, & it with 0x7fff.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's research the problem resided in the XC8 environment. It's a bug in the Rand() function, based on whether the environment is set up for C90 or C99 (C99 resulted in this problem).

The Microchip website link that describes the bug is here:
https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1077569.aspx *[Rand() Works with C90 Standard but not C99 Standard set in current project]*